# What is the difference hashing power when running the JS Monero Miner via a browser vs Running solo Mining with the cli?

Tags: mining-pools, mining, javascript, coin-hive

Just learned about the js miner for monero https://coin-hive.com -

- What is the difference in hashing power when mining through the browser using this method and doing it via the command line as a solo miner?
- Since your mining in your browser for coin-hive, so are they a pool miner?
- How do you cash out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They claim "65% of the performance of a native Miner", and this seems to be roughly the case on my PC.

This is definitely a pooled mining setup, and they're running their own pool. Which means if you want to cash out, you need to ask them to let you cash out through their web site.

Comment: I guess it depends on your native miner or some other circumstances. Their version consistently works at around 20-25% of native speed for my CPU.